# Gradle: Invalid publication 'maven': artifact file does not exist

Tags: maven, gradle, java-11, gradle-plugin, maven-publish

Java 11 and Gradle 7.2 here. I am trying to build a reusable library that I can (eventually) publish to a Maven repository and pull into other projects. But first I just want to get it publishing to my local m2 repo.

The project directory structure looks like:

```
mylib/
  lib/
    src/
    build.gradle
```

Where `build.gradle` is:

```
plugins {
  id 'java-library'
  id 'maven-publish'
  id 'io.freefair.lombok' version "6.5.0-rc1"
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.11
targetCompatibility = 1.11
archivesBaseName = 'mylib'
version = '1.0.0-RC1'
group = 'org.example'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  // omitted for brevity
)

testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2'
}

publishing {
  publications {
      maven(MavenPublication) {
        artifact("build/libs/${archivesBaseName}-${version}.jar") {
        extension 'jar'
      }
    }
  }
}

tasks.named('test') {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}

publishToMavenLocal.configure {
  mustRunAfter build
}
```

When I run `gradle publishToMavenLocal` I get:

```
% ./gradlew clean build publishToMavenLocal

> Task :lib:publishMavenPublicationToMavenLocal FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':lib:publishMavenPublicationToMavenLocal'.
> Failed to publish publication 'maven' to repository 'mavenLocal'
   > Invalid publication 'maven': artifact file does not exist: '/Users/myuser/workspace/mylib/lib/build/libs/mylib-1.0.0-RC1.jar'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 833ms
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed
```

So it looks like even though I'm specifying (on the command line) to run `clean` *then* `build` *then* `publishToMavenLocal`, and even though I'm even specifying (in `build.gradle`) that `publishToMavenLocal` must run *after* `build`, it seems what is happening is:

1. `publishToMavenLocal` **insists** on running first (before `clean` or `build`)
2. Since the JAR hasn't been built yet, no JAR file exists at the location specified (`"build/libs/${archivesBaseName}-${version}.jar"`)
3. The build fails because the artifact doesn't exist

So I *think* I just need to get `build` to run before `publishToMavenLocal` but I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing the [plugins DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block) (`plugins { }`) with [legacy plugin application](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:old_plugin_application) (`apply plugin`). That's not a big deal, but you should go with @sean's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72625421/5006866) and use the plugins DSL instead which will solve your issue.

To your problem at hand

> Could not get unknown property 'plugin'

That happens because you missed the `:` in `apply plugin`

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try placing your plugins in this way. Not sure if that resolves your issue though.

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
}
```

Comment: Asker already has these plugins defined.

Comment: I cannot remember what the question looked like before the edit but according to the accepted answer by @thokuest asker mixed `plugins{}` and `apply plugin`, which was why I suggested to define the plugin in the way I mentioned above. Not that the plugin was missing.